# Изменение цвета текста ячейки в table widget pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate, qcolor

Не поможете сделать функцию для изменения цвета текста определенной ячейки, указанную в координатах (1, 3) в table widget pyqt5?

1, 3 это столбец 1, строка 3

Comment: покажите ваш код и лучше расскажите что такое `в координатах (1, 3)`

Comment: Я не знаю какой код показывать, если я вообще не имею представления как это делать. 1, 3 это столбец 1, строка 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс [**QStyledItemDelegate**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#details) предоставляет средства отображения и редактирования элементов данных из модели.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableWidget 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette, QFont


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() == 3 and index.column() == 1 :
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("red"))
        else:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("#2D2424"))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = QTableWidget(5, 5)
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column0','Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'])
    w.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['Row0','Row1','Row2','Row3','Row4'])
    w.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate())
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как можно сделать измение цвета по действию, например: нажатие кнопки. То есть сначала текст обычный черный, а после нажатия на кнопку он меняет цвет?

Comment: @Morux  вы спросили как изменить цвет текста ячейке QTableWidget, я вам ответил. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.