# Изменение цвета текста определенной ячейки QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate, qcolor

Подскажите, пожалуйста исходя из [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455318/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-table-widget-pyqt5) темы, как можно изменять текст в определенной ячейке, указанной координатами (`column`, `row`)?

Это не должна быть одна какая-то ячейка. По задумке скрипт будет проверять 
"кое-что" и исходя результата этой проверки окрашивать нужную ячейку.

Проблема в логике окрашивания. Не могу понять, как самому указать координаты необходимой ячейки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.row = None
        self.column = None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() == self.row and index.column() == self.column:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("red"))
        else:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("#2D2424"))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def row_column(self, row=None, column=None):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
       

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
     
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(5, 5)
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()   
        columns = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, QTableWidgetItem(f'{r}{c}'))
        
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Column0','Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'])
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(
            ['Row0','Row1','Row2','Row3','Row4'])
        
        self.delegate = ColorDelegate()
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)   
        
        self.row_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.row_spinbox.setRange(0, 5)
        self.row_spinbox.setPrefix(" row ->   ") 
        self.row_spinbox.setProperty("value", 5)
        self.row_spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.qspinbox_value_changed)
        
        self.column_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.column_spinbox.setRange(0, 5)
        self.column_spinbox.setPrefix(" column ->   ") 
        self.column_spinbox.setProperty("value", 5)
        self.column_spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.qspinbox_value_changed)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.row_spinbox, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.column_spinbox, 1, 1)

    def qspinbox_value_changed(self, new_value):   
        row = self.row_spinbox.value()
        column = self.column_spinbox.value()
        self.delegate.row_column(row=row, column=column)
        self.tableWidget.setFocus()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 14, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое PyQt5.Qt? У меня такой библиотеки нету, из-за этого возникает с QTableWidgetItem, QSpinBox, QGridLayout

Comment: @Morux я заменил эту строку, проверьте.

Comment: @Morux что не так?

Comment: Работает как надо, но как изменять цвет в нескольких ячейках одновременно? В моем случае окрашивается только последний окрашиваемый элемент.

Comment: @Morux Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить его как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте НОВЫЙ вопрос, приведите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457127/Одновременное-изменение-цвета-ячеек-qtablewidget