# Одновременное изменение цвета текста в ячейках QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate, qcolor

Как сделать одновременную смену цвета в ячейках `QTableWidget` *PyQt5*? [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455744/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-qtablewidget/1455817?noredirect=1#comment2604570_1455817)

Comment: О каких ячейках вы говорите? Объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать. Покажите что вы пытались сделать и что у вас получилось.

Comment: например функция setColor с аргументами (2, 4, "red"), где 2 - столбец, 4 - строка, red - цвет текста.   И чтобы данная функция работала с одновременно несколькими ячейками. То есть, чтобы за одно выполнение определенного скрипта, ячейки могли краситься одновременно в разных местах.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.items = {}                                                   # +++


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        row_column = (index.row(), index.column())
# ---------------------------> vvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------ # !!!
        color = self.items.get(row_column)
        if color:
# --------------------------------------------------------> v vvvvv <---- # !!!
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(f"#{color}"))
        else:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("#2D2424"))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def row_column(self, items):
        self.items = items
       

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
     
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(5, 5)
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()   
        columns = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, QTableWidgetItem(f'{r}{c}'))
        
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Column0','Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'])
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(
            ['Row0','Row1','Row2','Row3','Row4'])
        
        self.delegate = ColorDelegate()
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)   

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.tableWidget_row_column_color = QTableWidget(5, 5)
        self.tableWidget_row_column_color.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Column0','Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'])
        self.tableWidget_row_column_color.setVerticalHeaderLabels(
            ['Row0','Row1','Row2','Row3','Row4'])

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cменить цвет')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.color_changed)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_row_column_color, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 1)

    def color_changed(self):   
        rows = self.tableWidget_row_column_color.rowCount()   
        columns = self.tableWidget_row_column_color.columnCount()
        items = {}
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                item = self.tableWidget_row_column_color.item(r, c)
                if item and item.text().strip():
                    items[(r, c)] = item.text()

        self.delegate.row_column(items)
        self.tableWidget.setFocus()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 14, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Morux что не так?